# Add transformer to node when clicked - KonvaJs

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs, konva

I am creating an application and having some issue in adding transformer to node when clicked, I have done creating a .on function and getting node instance by evt.target but don't know how to attach transformer to  node, There is a twist I have dynamically generated squares and I want to attach one transformer to one layer in the stage. As in many software you select the element in order to resize it.

```
  simpleText.on('dragmove', function(evt) {
    var shape = evt.target;
     //No instance of layer 
    console.log(evt.target);
    //If it returns any instance of layer then I would make new transformer and attach this node to it and to layer. 

});
```

Comment: This demos shows how to attach transformer to a target of event https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Basic_demo.html#page-title

Comment: @lavrton is there any function to get layer from the element? (Means I have rect I want it's layer to draw?)

Comment: got it `.getLayer()`